# Python: Cannot use module inside package

Tags: python, import, module

I've got some code in a module

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

import reusable

from state import state

class TitleState(state.State):
    def __init__(self):
        #Create data batches
        self.soundbatch = reusable.resourceloader.ResourceBatch(path="data/sound", type="ogg")
        self.imagebatch = reusable.resourceloader.ResourceBatch(path="data/image", type="tga")

        #Reusable stuff
        self.inputengine = reusable.inputengine.InputEngine()
        self.mousehandler = reusable.mousehandler.MouseHandler()

    def update(self):
        pygame.event.pump()
```

But it gives me the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\MegaCity\Start.py", line 1, in <module>
    import megacity.megacity
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\MegaCity\megacity\megacity.py", line 37, in <module>
    themc = MegaCity()
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\MegaCity\megacity\megacity.py", line 25, in __init__
    self.titlestate = titlestate.TitleState()
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\MegaCity\state\titlestate.py", line 21, in __init__
    self.inputengine = reusable.inputengine.InputEngine()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'inputengine'
```

However, the directory of reusable certainly has 'inputengine' in it:

```
 Directory of C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\MegaCity\reusable

10/09/2012  05:29 PM    <DIR>          .
10/09/2012  05:29 PM    <DIR>          ..
10/08/2012  09:34 PM             3,920 inputengine.py
10/09/2012  04:54 PM             1,364 mousehandler.py
10/08/2012  09:42 PM               799 resourceloader.py
10/09/2012  05:32 PM                 2 __init__.py
10/09/2012  05:32 PM    <DIR>          __pycache__
```

But, when I do `from reusable import inputengine` it imports `inputengine` just fine. Also, when in the `__init__.py` of reusable I put `from . import inputengine` the code works. Any insight into this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how it's supposed to work (not a bug, but a feature).

You have to include the packagename in your imports with absolute imports, if you don't want to do that you can use relative imports as you found out (i.e. `from . import inputengine`).

Comment: Weird. It seems that this would not be necessary, but whatever. I'll accept in 6 minutes.